# Actualizar con un trigger un campo de la misma tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Quisiera poder actualizar un campo de la misma tabla de donde se dispara el `Trigger`, he leído que cuando el `trigger` se dispara la tabla se bloquea y no se puede modificar pero que se puede realizar de otra manera.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `codigo_barras_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `persona`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE codigoEAN VARCHAR(13);
   Select CONCAT('1000',LEFT(NEW.nif, 8), '0') INTO codigoEAN;
   UPDATE  persona SET codigo_barras =  codigoEAN  WHERE nif = NEW.nif; 
END;
```

Lo que quiero realizar es actualizar el código de barras con el `NIF` de la persona, entonces siempre que se modifique el `NIF` que salte el `trigger` y genere el nuevo código de barras y lo guarde en la tabla persona. El inconveniente está en que el `NIF` y el código de barras se encuentra en la misma tabla. ¿Habría posibilidad de poder hacerlo o poder realizarlo de otra manera?

Comment: *he leido que cuando el trigger se dispara la tabla se bloquea*: ¿Puedes compartir la referencia que leístes por favor?

Comment: Es el 2º comentario. http://www.forosdelweb.com/f86/trigger-con-update-misma-tabla-616403/

Comment: Ah ok, ahora comprendo. En efecto, el efectuar una sentencia `UPDATE` dentro de un trigger para el mismo registro que está en curso de modificación es problemático. Por eso, si usas un *BEFORE UPDATE* trigger, en vez de un *AFTER UPDATE* trigger, no necesitas efectuar un `UPDATE` dentro del trigger, y así te evitas el problema descrito en ese enlace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En vez de usar un `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, puedes usar un `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger. En ese caso, tienes la oportunidad de asignar el valor a un campo *antes* que complete la sentencia `UPDATE`. No tienes que preocuparte de ningún bloqueo de la tabla porque no necesitas efectuar un `UPDATE` dentro del trigger. Solo necesitas asignar el valor al campo directamente.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de usar un `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger para tu caso:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `codigo_barras_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `persona`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  SET NEW.codigo_barras = CONCAT('1000',LEFT(NEW.nif, 8), '0');
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Ya he arreglado el error en el código, ya he puedo el codigoEAN donde correspondia en el UPDATE. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si que me sirve la solución, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa sería utilizar un Stored Procedure en lugar de un Trigger. El UPDATE se haría a través de este procedimiento y en el mismo procedimiento generar el script que desees.

A este procedimiento le pasas el nuevo NIF y antes de hacer el UPDATE lo modificas como estás haciendo en el Trigger.

[Este enlace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) te puede ser útil.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a intentar hacerlo con lo que me has compartido y si consigo la solución la comparto. Por cierto el enlace está mal, lo vuelvo a poner https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

Comment: Corregido @Arkhan6