# Crear un trigger para copiar valor de una campo a otro campo dentro de una misma tabla en mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger

Buenas necesito ayuda por favor si alguien podria darme un ejemplo para copiar el valor de un campo a otro campo de una misma tabla, cuando actualice el primer campo. gracias

Answer (score 0):

### Esta pregunta ya tiene solución en:

> [Actualizar con un trigger un campo de la misma tabla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49386/actualizar-con-un-trigger-un-campo-de-la-misma-tabla)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, vi el enlace basandome en eso hice el siguiente codigo puedes ver si esta correcto(costoactual es el campo con el valor que quiero pasar a precio1): 
CREATE TRIGGER `precio_final_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `inventario`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE  inventario SET precio1 =  codigoEAN  WHERE costoactual= NEW.costoactual; 
 END;

Comment: @DavidRivera no olvides usar el formato requerido para publicar código.  Saludos.